# Angular 17: select correct ElementRef of children component on mouseover event

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, draggable, resizable, angular-standalone-components

I am constructing draggable and resizable elements in a circumscribed area.
When I hover these elements I dynamically apply sensitive dots (red squares) over them so that I can also perform resizing.
The problem is that on mouseover the correct element reference is the entire dom and not the specific element.
To better understand the problem try the test on stackblitz and look at the behavior of the red squares on mouseover and after dragging container start when they are correctly positioned.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-igouxy

[image]

Comment: Use mouseenter instead of mouseover in your case. If you have child elements inside the container, you will have a lot of unnecessary events and resizers.

Comment: Great, it was my performance problem, solved with you suggestion!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `position: relative;` to `.table-area`. This is because the element with `position: absolute` is positioned relative to its closest positioned (not static) ancestor.