# Angular 17: drag and resize, something wrong in component isolation

Tags: angular, drag-and-drop, resizable, angular-standalone-components, angular17

I have two problems that I cannot identify:

1. When I resize the container2 the container1 is translated vertically.
2. When I switch to resize container1 after 2, the resize works differently, in fact instead of stretching at the drag point it also stretches in the other direction.

Theoretically the component should be isolated from the others, but evidently something is wrong but I can't figure it out.

Link to stackblitz project: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-igouxy

[image]

Comment: To fix your issue and for better performance use `position: absolute` on your draggable/resizable blocks

Comment: I can’t for this reason https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77809886/angular-17-select-correct-elementref-of-children-component-on-mouseover-event/77809919#77809919

Comment: Not clear what is the expected result. Not clear why you need inline-flex and align-items-center. Why not position absolute?

Comment: Ok you are right, my mistake, with position absolute it perform as expected. Thank you both